# Tic-Tac-Toe en C++ (Opiniones y ayuda para mejorar comandos Player Vs Pc)

Tags: c++, revisión-de-código

Hola a Todos aquí les dejo mi codigo hecho en C++ del famoso juego **Tic-Tac-Toe**.

La verdad es que aun estoy aprendiendo en este lenguaje por mi cuenta y me gustaria que me dieran sus opiniones de que deberia de editar o mejorar en mi codigo, ademas que quisiera lograr que las decisiones tomadas por el ordenador a la hora de jugar Player vs Pc sean mas realisticas o mejores planeadas.

En estos momentos solo se me ocurrio utilizar los valores aleatorios provistos por la funcion `srand(time(0));`

Se que tendra muchos bugs y errores asi que espero que alguien pueda ayudar me a corregirlos como es debido. Nada este es mi primera pregunta y espero que le sea de agrado y quizas a alguien le sirva de ayuda.

**P.D.** Utilice la libreria `Windows.h` para utilizar la funcion de `Sleep`, ya que es una libreria grafica si no la tienen instalada al tratar de compilar el codigo es muy probable que les salga error.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

//Prototipos
void board (char [3][3],char [11],char [11]);
void menu  (char [3][3],char&,char [11],char [11]);
void Input (char [3][3],char&);
void TogglePlayer(char&);
char Checkmate   (char [3][3]);
void game (char [3][3],char&,char [11],char [11]);
void resetboard(char [3][3]);
void AI (char[3][3],char&,char[11],char[11]);
void PCInput (char[3][3],char&);

int main()
{
    //Variables     
    char Player = 'X' ;
    char Nombre   [11];
    char Nombre_2 [11];
    char numeros [3][3]={{'1','2','3'},
                         {'4','5','6'},
                         {'7','8','9'}};


    menu (numeros,Player,Nombre,Nombre_2);                                           //Funcion donde se encuentra el menu y las opciones de juego


    return 0;
}

//Tablero de Juego
void board (char numeros[3][3],char Nombre [11],char Nombre_2 [11])
{
    int i,j;
    int filas=3,columnas=3;

    system("cls");
                                                                                        //Nos Muestra a los Jugadores Y Sus Respectivos Simbolos para Jugar.
    cout << "\t\t\t\tTic Tac Toe\n\n\n";
    cout << "\t      Player 1: " << Nombre <<" (X)  -  Player 2: "<< Nombre_2 <<" (O)" << endl << endl << endl << endl;

    for(i=0;i<columnas;i++)                                                             //Se Encarga de las Columnas del Tablero.
    {
        cout<<"\t\t\t       ";cout<<"  ";                                                               
        for(j=0;j<filas;j++)                                                            //Se Encarga de las Filas del Tablero.
        {   
            cout<<numeros[i][j];                                                        //Los Numeros del Arreglo se iran Acomodando en el Orden Correspondiente Mediante 
            if(j<filas-1)                                                               //Las Columnas Junto A las FiLas se Formen.                                                                                     
            {
                cout<<" | ";                                                            //Divisiones Verticales para el Tablero.
            }
        }
        cout<<endl;                                                                     //Salto de Linea, Nos Ayuda a Comenzar los Preparativos para las Divisiones Horizontales.

    if(i<filas-1)
        {
            for (int lines=0;lines<1;lines++ )                                          //Se Encarga de las Filas del Tablero.
            {
                cout<<"\t\t\t\t--- --- ---";                                            //Divisiones Horizantales para el Tablero.
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }

    }
    return;
}

//Menu
void menu (char numeros[3][3],char& Player,char Nombre [11],char Nombre_2 [11])
{
    int opcion,Opcion2;
    char continuar = 'Y';

    resetboard(numeros);                                                                //Resetboard Nos Colocara los Numeros del Arreglo en Orden Una Vez Finalizado la Primera Partida.

    cout << "\t\t\t\tTic Tac Toe\n\n\n";
    cout << "\t\t       Player 1 (X)  -  Player 2 (O)" << endl << endl;
    cout << "\n\n\n1)Start New Game\n2)Help\n3)Exit";
    cout << "\n\n\nOption: ";cin>>opcion;

    if (opcion==1)                                                                      //Opcion 1 Nos Lleva Directo a la Entrada del Juego.
    {   
        system("cls");  
        cout << "Choose a Number to Start Playing\n\n";
        cout << "1. Player vs Player\n2. Player vs PC\n\nOption: ";cin>>Opcion2;
        if(Opcion2==1)
        {
            game (numeros,Player,Nombre,Nombre_2);
        }
        else if (Opcion2==2)
        {
            AI (numeros,Player,Nombre,Nombre_2);
        }
    }
    else if (opcion==2)                                                                 //Opcion 2 Nos Permite Observar las Instrucciones Basicas del Juego.
    {
        system("cls");  
        cout<<"\n\nInstructions:\n\n"
            <<"\tThis Game is for Two Players, X and O, Who Take Turns Marking the\nSpaces in a 3x3 Grid."
            <<"The Player Who Succeeds in Placing Three of Their Marks \nin a Horizontal,Vertical, or Diagonal Row Wins the Game."
            <<"\n\nIn This Game the First Person to Play is X and the Second One is O.\n\nI Hope the Instructions have been Helpful, Have Fun! \2";
        system("Pause>Null");
        system("cls");
        menu (numeros,Player,Nombre,Nombre_2);
    }
    else if (opcion==3)                                                                 //opcion 3 Salir del Juego.
    {
        cout<<"\n\nThank You for Your Time, Until the Next!\n\n";
        system("Pause>Null");
    }                                                                               
else if ((opcion!=1)||(opcion!=2)||(opcion!=3))                                         //Esta Opcion nos dice que mientras el usuario no aplique una de las tres opciones anteriores el programa mostrara un mensaje.
    {
        cout<<"\n\nThe Number Entered is Incorrect, Please Try Again";
        system("Pause>Null");
        system("cls");
        menu (numeros,Player,Nombre,Nombre_2);
    }
    return;
}

//Entrada de Datos por Parte de los Usuarios
void Input(char numeros[3][3], char& Player)
{
    int NumField;

    cout << "\n\nIt's " << Player << " Turn. " <<"Press the Number of the Field: ";cin >> NumField; //Permite que el Usuario Marque El lugar de Preferencia para Su Tirada.
    //Campo de Tiro
    if (NumField == 1)
    {
        if (numeros[0][0] == '1')
            numeros[0][0] = Player;
        else
        {
            cout << "\nField is Already in Use Try Again!" << endl;
            Input(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else if (NumField == 2)
    {
        if (numeros[0][1] == '2')
            numeros[0][1] = Player;
        else
        {
            cout << "\nField is Already in Use Try Again!" << endl;
            Input(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else if (NumField == 3)
    {
        if (numeros[0][2] == '3')
            numeros[0][2] = Player;
        else
        {
            cout << "\nField is Already in Use Try Again!" << endl;
            Input(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else if (NumField == 4)
    {
        if (numeros[1][0] == '4')
            numeros[1][0] = Player;
        else
        {
            cout << "\nField is Already in Use Try Again!" << endl;
            Input(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else if (NumField == 5)
    {
        if (numeros[1][1] == '5')
            numeros[1][1] = Player;
        else
        {
            cout << "\nField is Already in Use Try Again!" << endl;
            Input(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else if (NumField == 6)
    {
        if (numeros[1][2] == '6')
            numeros[1][2] = Player;
        else
        {
            cout << "\nField is Already in Use Try Again!" << endl;
            Input(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else if (NumField == 7)
    {
        if (numeros[2][0] == '7')
            numeros[2][0] = Player;
        else
        {
            cout << "\nField is Already in Use Try Again!" << endl;
            Input(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else if (NumField == 8)
    {
        if (numeros[2][1] == '8')
            numeros[2][1] = Player;
        else
        {
            cout << "\nField is Already in Use Try Again!" << endl;
            Input(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else if (NumField == 9)
    {
        if (numeros[2][2] == '9')
            numeros[2][2] = Player;
        else
        {
            cout << "\nField is Already in Use Try Again!" << endl;
            Input(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "\nThe Number Entered is Out of Range" << endl;
        Input(numeros,Player);
    }
    return;
}

//Cambio de Turno
void TogglePlayer(char& Player)
{
    if (Player == 'X')                                                                          //Mientras la Variable Player sea X al llegar aqui Pasara a Convertrise en O.
        {
            Player = 'O';
        }
    else                                                                                        //Mientras la Variable Player sea O al llegar aqui Pasara a Convertirse en X.
        {
            Player = 'X';
        }
    return;
}

//Funcion que Dicta al GANADOR
char Checkmate(char numeros[3][3])
{
    //Player 1
     if (numeros[0][0] == 'X' && numeros[0][1] == 'X' && numeros[0][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
     if (numeros[1][0] == 'X' && numeros[1][1] == 'X' && numeros[1][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
     if (numeros[2][0] == 'X' && numeros[2][1] == 'X' && numeros[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

     if (numeros[0][0] == 'X' && numeros[1][0] == 'X' && numeros[2][0] == 'X')
        return 'X';
     if (numeros[0][1] == 'X' && numeros[1][1] == 'X' && numeros[2][1] == 'X')
        return 'X';
     if (numeros[0][2] == 'X' && numeros[1][2] == 'X' && numeros[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

     if (numeros[0][0] == 'X' && numeros[1][1] == 'X' && numeros[2][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';
     if (numeros[2][0] == 'X' && numeros[1][1] == 'X' && numeros[0][2] == 'X')
        return 'X';

    //Player 2
     if (numeros[0][0] == 'O' && numeros[0][1] == 'O' && numeros[0][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
     if (numeros[1][0] == 'O' && numeros[1][1] == 'O' && numeros[1][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
     if (numeros[2][0] == 'O' && numeros[2][1] == 'O' && numeros[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

     if (numeros[0][0] == 'O' && numeros[1][0] == 'O' && numeros[2][0] == 'O')
        return 'O';
     if (numeros[0][1] == 'O' && numeros[1][1] == 'O' && numeros[2][1] == 'O')
        return 'O';
     if (numeros[0][2] == 'O' && numeros[1][2] == 'O' && numeros[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

     if (numeros[0][0] == 'O' && numeros[1][1] == 'O' && numeros[2][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';
     if (numeros[2][0] == 'O' && numeros[1][1] == 'O' && numeros[0][2] == 'O')
        return 'O';

    //Draw
else if (numeros[0][0] != '1' && numeros[0][1] != '2' && numeros[0][2] != '3' && numeros[1][0] != '4' &&
         numeros[1][1] != '5' && numeros[1][2] != '6' && numeros[2][0] != '7' && numeros[2][1] != '8' && numeros[2][2] != '9')
        return 'D';
}

//Controla la Parte Fundamental del Juego 
void game (char numeros[3][3],char& Player,char Nombre [11],char Nombre_2 [11])
{
    char continuar = 'Y';

    system("cls");
    cout << "Please Enter Identifiers:\n"
         << "Hint: Only a Maximum of 10 Characters Allowed\n";
    cout << "\nPlayer 1 (Name/Initial): ";cin>>Nombre;                                          //Nombre del Primer Jugador Ingresado por el Usuario.
    cout << "\nPlayer 2 (Name/Initial): ";cin>>Nombre_2;                                        //Nombre del Segundo Jugador Ingresado por el Usuario.
    board (numeros,Nombre,Nombre_2);

    while(true)                                                                                 //Mientras el Juego No Encuentre a Un Ganador o Un Empate Seguira Corriendo.
        {
            Input(numeros,Player);
            board (numeros,Nombre,Nombre_2);

        if (Checkmate(numeros) =='X')
            {
                cout << "\nX wins!" << endl;break;
            }
        else if (Checkmate(numeros) =='O')
            {
                cout << "\nO Wins!" << endl;break;
            }
        else if (Checkmate(numeros) == 'D')
            {
                cout << "\nIt's a Draw!" << endl;break;
            }   
                TogglePlayer(Player);       
        }
    cout<<"\n\n\nDo You Want to Return to the Start Menu?: ";cin>>continuar;                    //Pregunta para Saber Si El Usuario Desea Continuar

    if((continuar=='y')||(continuar=='Y'))
            {
                system("cls");
                menu (numeros,Player,Nombre,Nombre_2);
            }
    return;
}

//Reinicia el Arreglo Llamado numeros, de Esta Manera se Puede Seguir Jugando sin Problemas Luego de Haber Finalizado la Primera Partida.
void resetboard(char numeros[3][3])
{   
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            numeros[0][0]='1';
            numeros[0][1]='2';
            numeros[0][2]='3';
            numeros[1][0]='4';
            numeros[1][1]='5';
            numeros[1][2]='6';
            numeros[2][0]='7';
            numeros[2][1]='8';
            numeros[2][2]='9';
        }   
    }
    return;     
}

//Practicamente es la misma funcion game() sin embargo esta modificada para poder jugar contra el mismo ordenador
void AI (char numeros[3][3],char& Player,char Nombre[11],char Nombre_2[11])
{
    char continuar = 'Y';
    Nombre_2 = "Computer(AI)";
    system("cls");
    cout << "Please Enter Identifiers:\n"
         << "Hint: Only a Maximum of 10 Characters Allowed\n";
    cout << "\nPlayer 1 (Name/Initial): ";cin>>Nombre;                                          //Nombre del Primer Jugador Ingresado por el Usuario.
    cout << "\nPlayer 2 (Name/Initial): " << Nombre_2;                                          //Nombre del Segundo Jugador.
    board (numeros,Nombre,Nombre_2);

    while(true)                                                                                 //Mientras el Juego No Encuentre a Un Ganador o Un Empate Seguira Corriendo.
        {
            Input(numeros,Player);
            board (numeros,Nombre,Nombre_2);
            TogglePlayer(Player); 

        if (Checkmate(numeros) =='X')
            {
                cout << "\nX wins!" << endl;break;
            }
        else if (Checkmate(numeros) =='O')
            {
                cout << "\nO Wins!" << endl;break;
            }
        else if (Checkmate(numeros) == 'D')
            {
                cout << "\nIt's a Draw!" << endl;break;
            }   

            PCInput (numeros,Player);
            board (numeros,Nombre,Nombre_2);
            TogglePlayer(Player);

        if (Checkmate(numeros) =='X')
            {
                cout << "\nX wins!" << endl;break;
            }
        else if (Checkmate(numeros) =='O')
            {
                cout << "\nO Wins!" << endl;break;
            }
        else if (Checkmate(numeros) == 'D')
            {
                cout << "\nIt's a Draw!" << endl;break;
            }  

        }
    cout<<"\n\n\nDo You Want to Return to the Start Menu?: ";cin>>continuar;                    //Pregunta para Saber Si El Usuario Desea Continuar

    if((continuar=='y')||(continuar=='Y'))
            {
                TogglePlayer(Player);
                system("cls");
                menu (numeros,Player,Nombre,Nombre_2);
            }
    return;
}

//Decisiones que tomara el ordenador
void PCInput (char numeros[3][3],char& Player)
{
    srand(time(0));
    int NumField = rand()%9+1;

    cout << "\n\nIt's " << Player << " Turn. "; 
    Sleep(2500);
    //Campo de Tiro
    if (NumField == 1)
    {
        if (numeros[0][0] == '1')
            numeros[0][0] = Player;
        else
        {
            PCInput(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else if (NumField == 2)
    {
        if (numeros[0][1] == '2')
            numeros[0][1] = Player;
        else
        {
            PCInput(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else if (NumField == 3)
    {
        if (numeros[0][2] == '3')
            numeros[0][2] = Player;
        else
        {
            PCInput(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else if (NumField == 4)
    {
        if (numeros[1][0] == '4')
            numeros[1][0] = Player;
        else
        {
            PCInput(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else if (NumField == 5)
    {
        if (numeros[1][1] == '5')
            numeros[1][1] = Player;
        else
        {
            PCInput(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else if (NumField == 6)
    {
        if (numeros[1][2] == '6')
            numeros[1][2] = Player;
        else
        {
            PCInput(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else if (NumField == 7)
    {
        if (numeros[2][0] == '7')
            numeros[2][0] = Player;
        else
        {
            PCInput(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else if (NumField == 8)
    {
        if (numeros[2][1] == '8')
            numeros[2][1] = Player;
        else
        {
            PCInput(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else if (NumField == 9)
    {
        if (numeros[2][2] == '9')
            numeros[2][2] = Player;
        else
        {
            PCInput(numeros,Player);
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "\nThe Number Entered is Out of Range" << endl;
        PCInput(numeros,Player);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Manuel, debes hacer una pregunta específica y concreta. Por ejemplo, si identificaste 100 errores con causas diferentes podrías hacer 100 preguntas, una para cada error, por supuesto, tendrías que incluir en cada una de ellas un __[mcve]__. El alcance de esta comunidad __no incluye__ opiniones, recomendaciones, ideas o [revisiones de código](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No se por que motivo se esta pidiendo el cierre, no digo que este mal o si, pero si esta pregunta entra dentro de esto "creo que si" -> https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio/235#164 estan  permitidas y es por esto mismo por lo que se pide el cierre pensando que este tipo de preguntas no estan permitidas cosa que si estan, al contrario que en SO.Saludos

Comment: ha simple vista donde usa -> cosas como estas `(NumField == 1)` y `else if` que son 7 u 8 por ejemplo, podria usar un `switch` para manejar esta situacion pues en mi opinion seria mas facil de entender y para usted en un futuro corregir o seguir el codigo, ademas de ser mas eficiente, tambien podria en lugar de lo anterior crear un array de punteros a funciones en las que ponga el codigo que corresponde a cada `if` en una funcion y añadir esas funciones al array de punteros donde el valor de `NumField == x` corresponda con la llamada a la funcion detro del array espero explicarme bien. Saludos

Comment: Tengo entendido que la publicacion fue cerrada por que mi pregunta es muy abierta y resultaria en un foro de opiniones, cierto?

Comment: @AngelAngel gracias por tu gran aporte, como dije en la publicacion aun estoy comenzando poco a poco y no tengo muchas habilidades todavia con los conceptos de C++. He leido detalladamente casi toda la informacion y puedo asegurarle que aprendere mucho mas gracias a esos conceptos. Respecto a los _for en resetboard_ fue algo que definitivamente no habia visto y es como dice estaba solo acumulando mas espacio y perdiendo eficiencia. Respecto a los _returns_ se que al ser funciones void no devuelven ningun valor, aun asi una profesora me indico que como buena practica siempre los usara

Comment: @ManuelAviles realize una pregunta para responder a su comentario, pues pienso que es mas sencillo de responder asi, que en un comentario, ademas de que podria ser util, para otros, o alguien con mas experiencia tenga otro punto de vista diferente al mio y lo pueda publicar en la pregunta -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/69740/es-buena-practica-usar-return-en-funciones-o-metodos-void/69741#69741 Saludos

Comment: El alcance de esta comunidad sí incluye revisiónes de código : https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/164/301 @Manuel: Lamento que la hayan cerrado incorrectamente, estamos intentando subsanarlo. Por favor cambia tu título a algo como "Tic-Tac-Toe en C++". Que quieres mejorarlo ya se da por sobreentendido al usar la etiqueta [tag:revisión-de-codigo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTA: saltar esta parte hasta leer primero el UPDATE**

---

La ultima idea del comentario es la siguiente, que es la misma seguida en este codigo es sobre un emulador:

Codigo inicial "simplificado" el switch era mucho mas grande aun el cual "simularia" el que a usted se le quedaria, si decide mover los if al switch (no tener en cuenta el codigo de dentro solo la idea, ademas es sacado de un sistema git con lo que es muy posble que las instrucciones en este punto estubiran algunas mal):

```html
     byte p = (opcode >> 12);
 
    // infernal switch temp_test opcode
    switch (p) {
        case 0:
            if (opcode == 0x00e0) {
                /*
                 * 00E0: CLS
                 * Clear the screen
                 */
                memset(cpu->screen, 0, 2048);
            } else if (opcode == 0x00ee) {
                /*
                 * 00EE: RET
                 * Return from subroutine.
                 */
                if (cpu->sp > 0)
                    cpu->pc = cpu->stack[--cpu->sp];
            }
            break;

        case 1:
            /*
             * 1NNN: JMP NNN
             * Jump to address location NNN.
             */
            cpu->pc = nnn;
            break;

        case 2:
            /*
             * 2NNN: CALL NNN
             * Call subroutine starting at address location NNN.
             */
            if (cpu->sp < 16)
                cpu->stack[cpu->sp++] = cpu->pc;
            cpu->pc = nnn;
            break;
        case 3:
            /*
             * 3XKK: SE X, KK
             * Skip next instruction if V[X] == KK
             */
            if (cpu->v[x] == kk)
                cpu->pc = (cpu->pc + 2) & 0xfff;
            break;

        case 4:
            /*
             * 4XKK: SNE X, KK
             * SKip next instruction if V[X] != KK
             */
            if (cpu->v[x] != kk)
                cpu->pc = (cpu->pc + 2) & 0xfff;
            break;

        case 5:
            /*
             * 5XY0: SE X, Y
             * Skip next instruction if V[X] == V[Y].
             */
            if (cpu->v[x] == cpu->v[y])
                cpu->pc = (cpu->pc + 2) & 0xfff;
            break;

        case 6:
            /*
             * 6XKK: LD X, KK
             * Set V[x] = KK.
             */
            cpu->v[x] = kk;
            break;

        case 7:
            /*
             * 7XKK: ADD X, KK
             * Add KK to V[X].
             */
            cpu->v[x] = (cpu->v[x] + kk) & 0xff;
            break;

        case 8:
           //..
            break;

        case 9:
            /*
             * 9XY0: SNE X, Y
             * Skip next instruction if V[x] != V[y].
             */
            if (cpu->v[x] != cpu->v[y])
                cpu->pc = (cpu->pc + 2) & 0xFFF;
            break;

        case 0xA:
            /*
             * ANNN: LD I, NNN
             * Will set I register to NNN.
             */
            cpu->i = nnn;
            break;

        case 0xB:
            /*
             * BNNN: JP V0, NNN
             * Will jump to memory address (V[0] + NNN).
             */
            cpu->pc = (cpu->v[0] + nnn) & 0xFFF;
            break;

        case 0xC:
            /*
             * CXKK: RND X, KK
             * Will get a random value, then bitmasking it using KK as an
             * AND mask, and then save that random value to V[x].
             */
            cpu->v[x] = rand() & kk;
            break;

        case 0xD:
        
            cpu->v[15] = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                byte sprite = cpu->mem[cpu->i + j];
                for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
                    int px = (cpu->v[x] + i) & 63;
                    int py = (cpu->v[y] + j) & 31;
                    int pos = 64 * py + px;
                    int pixel = (sprite & (1 << (7-i))) != 0;

                    cpu->v[15] |= (cpu->screen[pos] & pixel);
                    cpu->screen[pos] ^= pixel;
                }
            }
            break;
```

Como puede ver es un switch complicado de mantener ect.

---

debajo puede ver como se movieron las instrucciones que se realizaban dentro del switch a las fuciones que serian agregas al array de punteros:

```html
    void 
    spC0_00E0_00EE (struct machine_t* cpu, word opcode, word nnn,
      byte kk, byte n, byte x, byte y, byte p){
        if (opcode == 0x00e0) {
          /*
           * 00E0: CLS
           * Clear the screen
           */
          memset(cpu->screen, 0, 2048);
        } else if (opcode == 0x00ee) {
          /*
           * 00EE: RET
           * Return from subroutine.
           */
          if (cpu->sp > 0)
     cpu->pc = cpu->stack[--cpu->sp];
        }
    }
    
    void 
    spC1_1NNN (struct machine_t* cpu, word opcode, word nnn,
        byte kk, byte n, byte x, byte y, byte p){
     /*
         * 1NNN: JMP NNN
         * Jump to address location NNN.
         */
        cpu->pc = nnn;
    }
    
    void 
    spC2_2NNN (struct machine_t* cpu, word opcode, word nnn,
        byte kk, byte n, byte x, byte y, byte p){
      /*
         * 2NNN: CALL NNN
         * Call subroutine starting at address location NNN.
         */
        if (cpu->sp < 16)
          cpu->stack[cpu->sp++] = cpu->pc;
        cpu->pc = nnn;
    }
    
    void 
    spC3_3XKK (struct machine_t* cpu, word opcode, word nnn,
        byte kk, byte n, byte x, byte y, byte p){
        /*
         * 3XKK: SE X, KK
         * Skip next instruction if V[X] == KK
         */
        if (cpu->v[x] == kk)
          cpu->pc = (cpu->pc + 2) & 0xfff;
    }
    
    void 
    spC4_4XKK (struct machine_t* cpu, word opcode, word nnn,
        byte kk, byte n, byte x, byte y, byte p){
        /*
         * 4XKK: SNE X, KK
         * SKip next instruction if V[X] != KK
         */
        if (cpu->v[x] != kk)
          cpu->pc = (cpu->pc + 2) & 0xfff;
    }
    
    void 
    spC5_5XY0 (struct machine_t* cpu, word opcode, word nnn,
        byte kk, byte n, byte x, byte y, byte p){
        /*
         * 5XY0: SE X, Y
         * Skip next instruction if V[X] == V[Y].
         */
        if (cpu->v[x] == cpu->v[y])
          cpu->pc = (cpu->pc + 2) & 0xfff;
    }
    
    void 
    spC6_6XKK (struct machine_t* cpu, word opcode, word nnn,
        byte kk, byte n, byte x, byte y, byte p){
        /*
         * 6XKK: LD X, KK
         * Set V[x] = KK.
         */
        cpu->v[x] = kk;
    }
    
    void 
    spC7_7XKK (struct machine_t* cpu, word opcode, word nnn,
        byte kk, byte n, byte x, byte y, byte p){
        /*
         * 7XKK: ADD X, KK
         * Add KK to V[X].
         */
        cpu->v[x] = (cpu->v[x] + kk) & 0xff;
    }
    
    void 
    spC9_9XY0 (struct machine_t* cpu, word opcode, word nnn,
        byte kk, byte n, byte x, byte y, byte p){
        /*
         * 9XY0: SNE X, Y
         * Skip next instruction if V[x] != V[y].
         */
        if (cpu->v[x] != cpu->v[y])
          cpu->pc = (cpu->pc + 2) & 0xFFF;
    } 
    
    void 
    spC0xA_ANNN (struct machine_t* cpu, word opcode, word nnn,
          byte kk, byte n, byte x, byte y, byte p){
        /*
         * ANNN: LD I, NNN
         * Will set I register to NNN.
                 */
        cpu->i = nnn;
    }
    
    void 
    spC0xB_BNNN (struct machine_t* cpu, word opcode, word nnn,
          byte kk, byte n, byte x, byte y, byte p){
        /*
         * BNNN: JP V0, NNN
         * Will jump to memory address (V[0] + NNN).
         */
        cpu->pc = (cpu->v[0] + nnn) & 0xFFF;
    }
    
    void 
    spC0xC_CXKK (struct machine_t* cpu, word opcode, word nnn,
          byte kk, byte n, byte x, byte y, byte p){
        /*
         * CXKK: RND X, KK
         * Will get a random value, then bitmasking it using KK as an
         * AND mask, and then save that random value to V[x].
         */
        cpu->v[x] = rand() & kk;
    }
    
    void 
    spC0xD_DXYN (struct machine_t* cpu, word opcode, word nnn,
          byte kk, byte n, byte x, byte y, byte p){
     
        cpu->v[15] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
          byte sprite = cpu->mem[cpu->i + j];
          for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
     int px = (cpu->v[x] + i) & 63;
     int py = (cpu->v[y] + j) & 31;
     int pos = 64 * py + px;
     int pixel = (sprite & (1 << (7-i))) != 0;
    
     cpu->v[15] |= (cpu->screen[pos] & pixel);
     cpu->screen[pos] ^= pixel;
          }
        }
    } 
    
    void 
    spC0xE_EX9E_EXA1 (struct machine_t* cpu, word opcode, word nnn,
        byte kk, byte n, byte x, byte y, byte p){
        if (kk == 0x9E) {
          /*
           * EX9E: SKP X
           * Skip next instruction if key indicated in V[x] is down.
           */
          if (is_key_down(cpu->v[x]))
     cpu->pc = (cpu->pc + 2) & 0xFFF;
        } else if (kk == 0xA1) {
          /*
           * EXA1: SKNP X
           * Skip next instruction if key indicated in V[x] is not down.
           */
          if (!is_key_down(cpu->v[x]))
     cpu->pc = (cpu->pc + 2) & 0xFFF;
        }
    }
```

Practicamente cada codigo que estaba dentro de un case: se movio a una funcion, para se llamadas recuperandolas del array.

---

debajo de puede ver como se añaden esas funciones a un array el cual sera el que se usara para acceder a las misma en lugar de usar el switch para realizar las acciones:

```html
procesarInstruccionesOpcodes ptrFunInstrucciones_p[16] = {&spC0_00E0_00EE,
          &spC1_1NNN,
          &spC2_2NNN,
          &spC3_3XKK,
          &spC4_4XKK,
          &spC5_5XY0,
          &spC6_6XKK,
          &spC7_7XKK,
          &spC8_sn,
          &spC9_9XY0,
          &spC0xA_ANNN,
          &spC0xB_BNNN,
          &spC0xC_CXKK,
          &spC0xD_DXYN,
          &spC0xE_EX9E_EXA1,
          &spC0xF_skk};
```

---

```html
 

//.. definiciones del typo para usarlas como puntero a funciones
typedef void (*procesarInstruccionesOpcodes)(struct machine_t*, word, word,
                                             byte, byte, byte, byte,
                                             byte);
procesarInstruccionesOpcodes instruccion_p;

//..
//prototipos de la funciones
void spC0_00E0_00EE   (struct machine_t*, word, word, byte,
                       byte, byte, byte, byte); //00E0: CLS "or" 00EE: RET "in if"                               
void spC1_1NNN        (struct machine_t*, word, word, byte,
                       byte, byte, byte, byte); //1NNN: JMP  NNN  

void spC2_2NNN        (struct machine_t*, word, word, byte,
                       byte, byte, byte, byte); //2NNN: CALL NNN                                                 
void spC3_3XKK        (struct machine_t*, word, word, byte,
                       byte, byte, byte, byte); //3XKK: SE   X, KK                                               
void spC4_4XKK        (struct machine_t*, word, word, byte,
                       byte, byte, byte, byte); //4XKK: SNE  X, KK                                               
void spC5_5XY0        (struct machine_t*, word, word, byte,
                       byte, byte, byte, byte); //5XY0: SE   X, Y                                                
void spC6_6XKK        (struct machine_t*, word, word, byte,
                       byte, byte, byte, byte); //6XKK: LD   X, KK                                               
void spC7_7XKK        (struct machine_t*, word, word, byte,
                       byte, byte, byte, byte); //7XKK: ADD  X, KK                                               
void spC8_sn          (struct machine_t*, word, word, byte,
                       byte, byte, byte, byte);

void spC9_9XY0        (struct machine_t*, word, word, byte,
                       byte, byte, byte, byte); //9XY0: SNE X, Y  

void spC0xA_ANNN      (struct machine_t*, word, word, byte,
                       byte, byte, byte, byte);  //ANNN: LD I, NNN                                               
void spC0xB_BNNN      (struct machine_t*, word, word, byte,
                       byte, byte, byte, byte);  //BNNN: JP V0, NNN                                              
void spC0xC_CXKK      (struct machine_t*, word, word, byte,
                       byte, byte, byte, byte);  //CXKK: RND X, KK                                               
void spC0xD_DXYN      (struct machine_t*, word, word, byte,
                       byte, byte, byte, byte);  //DXYN: X, Y, N                                                 
void spC0xE_EX9E_EXA1 (struct machine_t*, word, word, byte,
                       byte, byte, byte, byte);  //EX9E: SKP X "or" EXA1: SKNP X "in if"                         
void spC0xF_skk       (struct machine_t*, word, word, byte,
                       byte, byte, byte, byte);
```

---

Abajo ahora que podemos ver como se desaparece el switch infernal por lo siguiente:

```html
//esto sustituye la funcion del switch, en su caso seria lo que sustituye a los if, o tambien al swtich si crea inicialmente uno, ademas de ser mucho mas eficiente, es mucho mas facil de mantener, esto ultimo en mi opinion 
void
algunNombre()
{
    
    byte p = (opcode >> 12);

  if (!(p < 0 || p > 15)){
    instruccion_p = ptrFunInstrucciones_p[p];
    instruccion_p(cpu, opcode, nnn, kk, n, x, y, p);
  }
}
```

---

Quizas se pregunte, por que no me dejas el codigo adaptado a mi codigo.

la respuesta es sencilla, mientras trata de entender como funciona asume mejor la idea y como esta esta implementada, si le dejo el codigo adaptado al suyo quizas lo copie lo pruebe y diga ahh ya lo estudiare, con lo que no aprenderia nada, ademas pienso que esta bien detallado, pues no es que simplemente le dejara el codigo sin mas.

Por otro lado quizas pueda pensar valla follon, o esto no es necesario para mi codigo, y puede ser que en ambas tenga mas o menos razon, pero si le digo que cuando entienda lo mostrado, pienso que obtendra un conocimiento nuevo bastante util para un futuro, y quizas hasta intente usarlo en todas partes, pero recuerde que cada cosa tiene su utilidad es su responsabilidad intentar usarlo de la mejor manera en el momento adecuado.

Por ultimo tomelo como una practica nueva en la que le piden sustituir un switch por algo mas eficiente, y le dan como opcion el uso de punteros a funciones.

---

Alguna info y notas:

lo anterior permite implementar el concepto (table-driven code) codigo dirigido por tabla.

- [idea basica](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/30580/how-to-declare-an-array-of-pointers-to-functions-in-visual-c)
- [algunos detalles](http://c.conclase.net/curso/?cap=020d)

Al entender como funciona lo podria usar para muchas otras cosas, por citar algun ejemplo.

Podria tener como es su caso que dependiendo del valor de una variable ejecute un determinado codigo, ahora imagine que esta creando un juego en el que el personaje evoluciona, y tiene otras habilidades, las habilidades que usaba dependian del valor de la variable mencionada, usted podria con este metodo, cambiar el array dinamicamente, sin tener que cambiar como se genera el valor de la variable ect.

Pues si ahora con el valor de la variable a 1 por ejemplo quiere que ejecute otro codigo, solo tendria que cambiar dentro del array para la posicion [1](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/30580/how-to-declare-an-array-of-pointers-to-functions-in-visual-c) a un nuevo puntero a funcion.

Si esto es algo enrevesado o quizas no, pero es para que puede ver alguna de sus fuciones.

---

## UPDATE

> .

Le dejo por aqui algo relacionado con la funcion `Checkmate`

```
#define S 3

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


//la parte del Draw exatamente no se por que la tiene 
//aun asi le dejo algo por aqui se llamaria como una 
//funcion a aparte por ejemplo usted le podria encontrar un buen lugar

char Draw(char numeros[S][S]){

    //se podria hacer una comprovacion con un for pero se tendria que
    //saber si tienen que se exatamente esos caracter para cada lugar 
    //del array o pueden ser otros

    if (numeros[0][0] != '1' && numeros[0][1] != '2' && numeros[0][2] != '3' && numeros[1][0] != '4' &&
         numeros[1][1] != '5' && numeros[1][2] != '6' && numeros[2][0] != '7' && numeros[2][1] != '8' && numeros[2][2] != '9')
        return 'D';
}

//test
char Checkmate_test_varia(char numeros[S][S])
{   
    char temp = 'D';
    bool toggle = true;

    int value_a = S;
    int value_aa = S;

    int matrix = S;

    for (int aa = 0; aa < value_aa; aa++){

        temp = 'D';

        int temp_p1_h = 0;
        int temp_p2_h = 0;

        int temp_p1_v = 0;
        int temp_p2_v = 0;

        int temp_p1_x = 0;
        int temp_p2_x = 0;

        int temp_p1_xx = 0;
        int temp_p2_xx = 0;

        for (int a = 0; a < value_a; a++){

            if (numeros[aa][a] != 'X'){
                temp_p2_h ++;
            }else{
                temp_p1_h ++;
            }

            if (numeros[a][aa] != 'X'){
                temp_p2_v ++;
            }else{
                temp_p1_v ++;
            }

            if(toggle == true){

                if (numeros[a][a] != 'X'){
                    temp_p2_x ++;
                }else{
                    temp_p1_x ++;
                }

                if (numeros[a][(value_a -1) -a] != 'X'){
                    temp_p2_xx ++;
                }else{
                    temp_p1_xx ++;
                }
            }        
        }

        if(toggle == true){

            toggle = false;

            if(temp_p1_x == matrix || temp_p1_xx == matrix){

                temp = 'X';
                aa = matrix + 10;

            }else if(temp_p2_x == matrix || temp_p2_xx == matrix){

                temp = 'O';
                aa = matrix + 10;

            }       
        }

        if(temp_p1_h == matrix || temp_p1_v == matrix ){

            temp = 'X';
            aa = matrix + 1;

        }else if(temp_p2_h == matrix || temp_p2_v == matrix){

            temp = 'O';
            aa = matrix + 1;

        } 
    }
return temp;
}
int main()
{

  char numeros [3][3]={  {'X','X','X'},
                         {'O','O','X'},
                         {'X','X','O'}};

  char numeros_matrix_mayores_test [4][4]={  {'O','O','X','X'},
                                             {'O','X','X','O'},
                                             {'X','X','O','X'},
                                             {'X','X','O','X'}};


  std::cout << Checkmate_test_varia(numeros);
  //std::cout << Checkmate_test_varia(numeros_matrix_mayores_test); //Cambiar para test el define #define S 4
}
```

---

es posible que su forma de hacerlo sea mas rapida para algunas combinaciones pero quizas esta forma sea mas rapida en general.

Seria bueno hacer un test sobre una simulacion de partidas
aleatorias usando los mismo datos y llamando a su funcion y controlar el tiempo que tarda e igual para la mia, y compararlos, ya sabe si se anima usted o alguien, estaria guay conocer los tiempos.

Por otro lado la mia, pienso es mas escalable que la suya, aunque tengo que decir que cuando la implemente, no pensaba hacerlo solo me centre en 3 X 3 pero luego me pico el gusanillo, para otro tipo de matrices 4 X 4 por ejemplo he hice alguno ajustes minimos.

No lo he testeado pero hacer eso en la suya seria mas engorroso, y en cuanto la matrix valla siendo mas grande aun mas, ademas pienso que ahi es cuando el tiempo se empezaria a disparar en su forma, y a mas grande mas y mas, pero solo es una "teoria" no lo he probado espero le ayude.

---

*P.D: y cosa curiosa tengo que decir que fue una pregunta entretenida, quizas deba empezar a aprender esto de los puzzles mira que nunca me llamo la curiosidad por eso, bueno saludos y gracias.*

> .

Le dejo algo sobre la funcion `Input` la cual es muy similar a `PCInput` la cual puede ajusta facilmente con lo de abajo.

tenia un rato libre y me pase otra vez por su pregunta, **y con lo de punteros a funciones quizas me precipite sin mirar bien como funcionaba lo que estaba dentro de los if**.

*le dejo la informacion sobre los punteros expuesta al principio para que la vea, pero es muy posible que lo borre de la respuesta*.

Notas: no se si esto es escalable para matrices mas grandes como lo anterior que le deje, no lo he testeado.

```
void Input_test(char numeros[3][3], char& Player)
{
    //despues de hacer lo de abajo he intentar probarlo me di cuenta que usted 
    //nunca asigna nada a NumField pero me imagino que el valor se lo parasara 
    //por por medio de algun parametro en la llamada a la funcion o similar y 
    //olvido ponerlo o de otra manera que ahora mismo no veo
    int NumField = 1; //valor para test

    int a = NumField / 3;

    if ((a % 3) == 0){
        a -=1;
    }

    int aa = NumField;

    if ((a % 3) == 0){
        aa -=1;
    }else{
        aa = (a % 3) - 1;
    }

    char temp[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'};

    bool c = true;

    if (numeros[a][aa] == temp[NumField]){

            numeros[a][aa] = Player;
            c = false;
    }else{

        cout << "\nField is Already in Use Try Again!" << NumField << endl;
        Input(numeros,Player);
        c = false;
    }


    if(c){
        cout << "\nThe Number Entered is Out of Range" << endl;
        Input(numeros,Player);
    }
    return;
}
```

> .

Sobre esta parte de su pregunta *Player vs Pc sean mas realisticas o mejores planeadas.*

imagino que lo anterior corresponde con esta parte del codigo:

```
void PCInput (char numeros[3][3],char& Player)
{
    srand(time(0));
    int NumField = rand()%9+1;
```

realmete no le sabria decir, pues para ser mas realistas, se tiene que saber jugar bien a ese juego, es decir conocer algunas estrategias si estas existen para ganar o tener mas posibilidades de hacerlo, he implementarlas para que el PCInput las use dependiendo del nivel ect, por ejemplo es lo que se me ocurre ahora mismo.

Por otro lado piense que esto `int NumField = rand()%9+1;` podria corresponderse con alguien que no sabe jugar pues no tiene nada encuenta "que tambien podria considerarse realista" o quizas con alguien con los ojos cerrados que pone las fichas donde caigan ja.

Esto es solo una idea imaginese que quiere que el `PCInput` en un determinado momento busque en que lugares del tablero en el que tiene un ficha para intentar colocarla al lado de esta.

Pues si quisiera hacer algo asi, seguro lo hace en un momento, podria buscar por el tablero o podria crear un array para el PCInput en el cual se vallan asigando las posiciones que el tiene, despues mirar determinar donde la podria poner y mirar si esa casilla esta libre y asi.

Pero seria basandose en niveles, bueno por lo menos ya tiene un nivel de dificualtad el random.

> .

Esta parte realmente no hace nada:

```
void resetboard(char numeros[3][3])
{   
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            numeros[0][0]='1';
            //..  
return;    
}
```

me refiero que los for anidados que tiene son solo para "perder" eficiencia en su programa, pues usted no hace algo asi `numeros[i][j]` asi que podria dejarlo sin los for:

```
void resetboard(char numeros[3][3])
{   
            numeros[0][0]='1';
            //..
    //return; // el return por que ?     
}
```

Comment: _realmete no le sabria decir, pues para ser mas realistas, se tiene que saber jugar bien a ese juego, es decir conocer algunas estrategias si estas existen para ganar o tener mas posibilidades de hacerlo, he implementarlas para que el PCInput las use dependiendo del nivel ect, por ejemplo es lo que se me ocurre ahora mismo._

Es lo que habia estado pensando, pero al igual desconozco si hay tipos de jugadas con las que pueda forzar un juego. De todas maneras le agradezco su interes. Definitivamente este tipo de Puzzle es muy entretenido pronto tratare con el juego de **Snake**