# Es buena practica usar 'return' en funciones o metodos 'void'

Tags: java, c#, c++

Pregunta realizada para contestar a un [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/69246/tic-tac-toe-en-c-opiniones-y-ayuda-para-mejorar-comandos-player-vs-pc/69319#comments-69246), de forma que se pueda entender mejor, y porque pienso puede ser una pregunta interesante y util para otros usuarios que quizas se pregunten lo mismo.

---

*Respecto a los returns se que al ser funciones void no devuelven ningun valor, aun asi una profesora me indico que como buena practica siempre los usara – Manuel Aviles*

Comment: No tiene ningún sentido hacer un return al final de un método void cuando la siguiente linea que se va a ejecutar es la de debajo de la llamada a dicho método void.. por lo tanto esta haciendo un return sin hacerlo. Quieres devolver algo? no verdad? pues entonces...

Comment: @AlvaroLopez-Pupila1992 entiendo por donde va su comentario pero  *...Quieres devolver algo? no verdad? ...* es que aunque quisiera no podria por la firma de la funcion que es `void` de intentarlo obtendria algo como **return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]** . Es por eso que expongo algun caso en el que pienso que el uso de return; seria util. Saludos

Comment: Hacer uso de return para una funcion con tipo de retorno void es util en ocaciones, por ejemplo, cuando se quiere salir de la funcion en determinada condición. En caso contrario, creo que es redundante hacer uso de return.

Answer (score 26):

> *Respecto a los returns se que al ser funciones void no devuelven ningun valor, aun asi una profesora me indico que como buena practica siempre los usara – Manuel Aviles*

#### Una importante distinción.

No tiene ninguna relevancia que una función devuelva un valor o no lo devuelva, una instrucción `return` se comportará de la misma manera en ambos casos: saldrá de la función en ejecución. La única diferencia consistirá en que junto con la instrucción `return` se devolverá (o no) un valor.

#### Salida temprana de la función.

Se considera salida temprana de una función el salir sin haber llegado al final de la función, esto se hace utilizando la instrucción `return`, que crea nuevos puntos de salida de la función a parte del final de la misma.

Como muchos otros temas de programación, el principio de salida única<sup>1</sup> está malinterpretado o descontextualizado o se abusa del mismo.

No hay nada de malo en salir de una función mediante una instrucción `return` en cualquier parte de una función (tanto si la función devuelve algo como si no).

Los mecanismos del lenguaje al salir de una función son los mismos tanto si se sale de manera temprana como si se sale por finalizar la función, la única posible diferencia consistiría en que ciertas instrucciones no se ejecutarían (evitando así sus [efectos secundarios](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efecto_secundario_(inform%C3%A1tica))) pero sucedería exactamente igual con una instrucción `if`.

#### Múltiples salidas de función ¿Cuál es el problema?.

Si no hay nada de malo en ello ¿Cuál es el problema?. No se trata de un problema de rendimiento si no de diseño, en algunas ocasiones tener varios puntos de salida de una función (tanto si devuelve algo como si no) hace que sea más difícil seguir la lógica de la función y en consecuencia será más difícil de depurar y trabajar con ella, algunos programadores defienden el el principio de salida única<sup>1</sup> por este motivo.

Otros programadores defienden el principio de salida única<sup>1</sup> por rendimiento, pero no va a haber ninguna diferencia de rendimiento entre seguir o no seguir este principio ni en [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) ni en [java](/questions/tagged/java) (ni en cualquier lenguaje de programación moderno) así que defender esa postura es tan sólo una malinterpretación del principio.

#### ¿Seguro que no hay problema?.

Podemos encontrar problemas con múltiples puntos de salida en una función (salidas tempranas de función) en [fortran](/questions/tagged/fortran) o [cobol](/questions/tagged/cobol) o [ensamblador](/questions/tagged/ensamblador) ya que en estos lenguajes este tipo de práctica es propensa a errores (no siguen las recomendaciones de [Edsger W. Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edsger_W._Dijkstra) sobre programación estructurada) al hacer posible que algunas variables queden sin inicializar o que cierto código crucial no se ejecute; pero se debe a particularidades de estos lenguajes, los lenguajes modernos no tienen estos problemas.

#### Estructurar el código.

Cuando se tiene una función larga que puede salir en varios puntos (devolviendo o sin devolver valor) podemos estructurarla como el [Acueducto de Amoreira](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acueducto_de_Amoreira)<sup>2</sup> o como el [Templo maldito](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Jones_and_the_Temple_of_Doom)<sup>2</sup>:

`Acueducto Amoreira`

```
if (condicion_1)
{
    // hacer cosas 1
    if (condicion_2)
    {
        // hacer cosas 2
        if (condicion_3)
        {
            // hacer cosas 3
            if (condicion_4)
            {
                // hacer cosas 4
                if (condicion_5)
                {
                    // hacer cosas 5
                    // ...
                }
                else
                {
                    // Otras cosas
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Otras cosas
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Otras cosas
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Otras cosas
    }
}
else
{
    // Otras cosas
}
```

`Templo Maldito`

```
if (!condicion_1)
{
    // Otras cosas, como salir de la función
    return;
}
// hacer cosas 1

if (condicion_2)
{
    // Otras cosas, como salir de la función
    return;
}
// hacer cosas 2

if (condicion_3)
{
    // Otras cosas, como salir de la función
    return;
}
// hacer cosas 3

if (condicion_4)
{
    // Otras cosas, como salir de la función
    return;
}
// hacer cosas 4

if (condicion_5)
{
    // Otras cosas, como salir de la función
    return;
}
// hacer cosas 5
```

En el Acueducto de Amoreira el código ondula a través de múltiples indentaciones (haciendo que parezca un acueducto) y la función fluye al final sin pasar por instrucciones `return`, hay un sólo punto de entrada y de salida. En El templo Maldito la función pasa diferentes pruebas y si no las supera sale con una instrucción `return`, hay un punto de entrada y varias salidas.

Ninguna de las dos estructuraciones es mejor que la otra, pero, según los gustos del programador: una será más sencilla de utilizar que la otra.

---

<sup>1</sup>Acabo de acuñar el nombre, no me consta que oficialmente se conozca así la práctica de tener un solo punto de salida en una función.

<sup>2</sup>Acabo de acuñar el nombre, no me consta que esta estructuración reciba este nombre.

Answer (score 4):

Primero que nada yo no soy nadie para juzgar a un profesor, pues es eso un profesor y solo el sabra el por que de esta recomendacion. Podria ser una metodologia para por ejemplo:

- Te acostumbres a poner return en las funciones y no se te olvide con lo que evitar errores de compilacion, mientras "aprendes".
- Quizas lo haga para explicar mas adelante otras cosas.
- O por cualquier otra cosa.

Dicho lo anterior en mi opinion tal como lo tiene usted o para una funcion similar aparte de ser confuso, pues se puede pensar que se olvido el tipo de retorno y la firma de la funcion esta mal o cualquier otra cosa, ejemplo de donde usted lo usa "o para casos similares":

```
void resetboard(char numeros[3][3])
{   
    for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
           //..  
return;    
}
```

En el caso anterior o similares bajo mi punto de vista no sirve de "nada".

---

Ahora bien existen alguno casos en los que si es util, para hacer mas eficiente una funcion con muchos `if - else` usando un patron que creo recordar se llama "patron del gorila", en el cual si es util bajo mi punto de vista, tomemos este ejemplo:

*su pongamos que la funcion `reset` puede recivir cualquier entero pues no es controlado anteriormente en la llamada a la funcion*

```
void reset(in numero)
{   
    if (numeros == 1)
    {

    }
    else if (numeros == 2)
    {

    }
    else if (numeros == 3)
    {

    }
    else if (numeros == 4)
    {

    }
    else if (numeros == 5)
    {

    }
    else if (numeros == 6)
    {

    }
    else if (numeros == 7)
    {

    }
    else if (numeros == 8)
    {

    }
    else if (numeros == 9)
    {

    }  
}
```

como puede ver lo anterior recorre los if hasta encontrar uno valido. Con lo que tiene que recorrer todos lo if - else, y ese funcion se puede llamar con cualquier int, con lo que de todos los valores que puede tener un int solo 9 son aceptados.

Ahora con el uso de 'return' puede hacer mas eficiente esa funcion sin tener que pasar por todos los if - else para un int que no es aceptado:

```
void reset(in numero)
{   
    if (numeros < 1 || numeros > 9)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (numeros == 1)
    {

    }
    else if (numeros == 2)
    {

    }
    else if (numeros == 3)
    {

    }
    //..
}
```

Ahora con esta parte:

```
    if (numeros < 1 || numeros > 9)
    {
        return;
    }
```

comprobamos que el numero este dentro del rango en el cual se realizan acciones, de no ser asi, salimos de la funcion, con lo que evitamos perder tiempo en comprobar todos los if - else, y si esa funcion se llama muchas veces como puede ser en el update de un juego, pues en este caso si que es muy util, para no consumir recursos en esa funcion mas de los necesarios.

Comment: Para tantas condiciones es recomendable usar un Switch. Sacando esto de lado si queres cortar el ciclo podes usar Break

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti aunque estoy de acuerdo con lo de usar un switch u otras cosas segun que lenguaje (punteros a funciones ect), no es el caso de esta pregunta, es por eso que no se menciona nada. Mas que nada por poner algun ejemplo, donde puede ser util este estilo, con la intencion de no seguir procesando x funcion si no se cumple un caso, podria no ser varios if - else podria ser unos for anidados y no quieres que se ejecuten si no se cumple una condicion o cualquier cosa.Saludos

Comment: De todas maneras puedes usar un Break en el if

Comment: @AlejandroRicotti "break" no funciona dentro de un "if". "break" es diseñado para su uso dentro de bucles (while, for, do-while, ect). Saludos

Comment: No veo cuál es la utilidad en un estilo que usa varios if-else si en el ejemplo que das es mucho mejor usar switch, que no sólo hace más legible el código sino que evita usar un return en un procedimiento. Creo que deberías haber puesto un ejemplo que ilustre mejor el uso de un return en una función void.

Answer (score 1):

Un consejo, mientras seas alumno de ese profesor usa los returns en todo el código que haya de ser visto por ese profesor, especialmente en un examen.

En cuanto al mundo real...
La tendencia general es a hacer los lenguajes lo menos verbosos posible. Por ejemplo, en un lenguaje moderno com Scala no solo se puede prescindir de un return en una función void, también se puede prescindir en una función que devuelve algo. Este sería el código (al estilo procedural) en Scala para sumar de 1 a 10:

```
def sumar = {
  var suma = 0
  for ( i <- 1 to 10 ) {
    suma += i
  }
  suma // Esta línea hace lo mismo que: return suma
}
```

En C++ esto no es posible. Vas a tener que poner `return suma` al final de una función que devuelva un entero. Pero puedes omitirlo en una función void. Y lo recomendable es omitirlo. La llave que cierra la función ya te está diciendo que la función acaba, no hace falta escribirlo dos veces.

Harina de otro costal es poner un return en medio de una función en una sentencia condicional para que acabe la función prematuramente. Ahí sí tiene sentido hacerlo.

Comment: es que ami personalmente veo un codigo con un return en una funcion similar a donde el usuario del comentario la usa, y lo primero que hago es mirar la firma de la funcion, si esta es void pienso quizas se olvido el return y puso mal la firma el return me refirero a que olvidara algo como `return value;` o pienso algo sobre esto, lo cual crea confusion como comente, al usar return en estos casos. Por otro lado buen consejo ese de  *...mientras seas alumno de ese profesor...* Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Cada docente, en realidad cada persona, tiene formas diferentes de programar.
Algunos prefieren:

```
main()
{
  int numero;
  printf("Ingrese un numero");
  scanf("%d", &numero);
}
```

otros:

```
main()
{
  int numero;
  numero = ingresar_numero();
}
```

otros:

```
main()
{
  int numero;
  ingresar_numero(&numero);
}
```

Aunque son 3 ejemplos sencillos, son 3 formas distintas de por ejemplo ingresar un número en el primer caso la lógica se incluye en el main, en el segundo caso la lógica se incluye en la función y la misma retorna el resultado, y en el tercer caso la lógica se incluye en la función y no retorna nada, ya que escribe en memoria.

Personalmente, prefiero que las funciones retornen "algo" aunque sea una variable bool que indique si la operación se realizó correctamente bajo algún criterio establecido.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Realmente no, solo te obliga a tener una salida, ya que seria un simple return y como es un metodo void no tiene el más minimo caso. Solo es una practica por constumbre, muchos lenguajes de generacion actual como Ruby evitan el uso de esta palabra ya que solo devuelve el ultimo elemento evaluado, el return es muy verboso.