# ¿Cómo salir correctamente de un "while" tras el uso de un "if"?

Tags: c#

Nose cual es la forma correcta de salir de un bucle While según el siguiente método.

```
    public bool ItemExist( object element, string name )
    {

        var eElement = (Enumerator) element ;

        while (eElement.MoveNext())
        {
            object item = eElement.Current;

            if(Invoke<bool> (item, "Exist", name))
            {
                return true;
                break; // Forzar salida del bucle ?
            }

        }

        return false;

    }
```

Con solamente el "return" o además tengo que poner "break"; ya cuando la condición es True quiero que salga del bucle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No existe una forma *correcta* de hacer lo que comentas, así pues no existe tampoco una respuesta *correcta* a tu pregunta.

La correctitud de cada solución dependerá de factores como el contexto y el [manual de estilo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_de_estilo) seguido en tu proyecto (de haberlo).

Así pues, a priori, el código que has puesto de ejemplo no es incorrecto en ningún sentido<sup>1</sup>, pero dependiendo del contexto puede ser más adecuado enfocar el mismo algoritmo de otra manera, por ello voy a presentar unas alternativas a tu código:

#### Pasa un `Enumerator` en lugar de un `object`.

```
public bool ItemExist( Enumerator element, string name )
{
    while (element.MoveNext())
    {
        object item = element.Current;

        if(Invoke<bool> (item, "Exist", name))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Esta aproximación es casi idéntica a la tuya con la diferencia que en lugar de recibir un `object` como primer parámetro recibimos directamente un `Enumerator`, esto es *más correcto* desde el punto de vista del [principio de responsabilidad única](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_responsabilidad_%C3%BAnica) ya que ahora tu función `ItemExist` sólo hace una cosa, que es la que promete: informar si un `Item` `Exist`e en la colección.

Antes, además de la búsqueda hacías una conversión de tipos que podía lanzar una [`InvalidCastException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.invalidcastexception(v=vs.110).aspx).

#### Punto de salida único.

Algunos programadores consideran más fácil trabajar con [funciones que tengan un único punto de salida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/69740/es-buena-practica-usar-return-en-funciones-o-metodos-void), dado que lo consideran más fácil, también lo consideran más correcto; esta versión ofrece precisamente eso:

```
public bool ItemExist( Enumerator element, string name )
{
    bool found = false;

    while (!found && element.MoveNext())
    {
        object item = element.Current;
        found = Invoke<bool> (item, "Exist", name);
    }

    return found;
}
```

Ahora la función tiene un punto de salida único (un sólo `return`) y el bucle se interrumpe en el momento en que se detecta la `Exist`encia del `Item`.

#### Usando [LINQ](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query).

Alternativamente puedes pasar la colección a tu función y realizar la búsqueda mediante LINQ:

```
public bool ItemExist<T>( IEnumerable elements, string name )
{
    return Enumerable.Any<T>(elements.GetEnumerator(),
        (object item) => { return Invoke<bool>(item, "Exist", name); });
}
```

Aunque para una llamada de una línea a LINQ, tal vez no valga la pena escribir la función :)

---

<sup>1</sup>Salvo que el `break` tras el `return true` nunca es alcanzado, como ha comentado [Carlos Muñoz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/100578/2742), el `break` interrumpe el bucle, no sale de la función.

Comment: El punto de salida única, se ve un código más limpio.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, aunque lamento discrepar del "punto de salida unico".  Esta idea proviene de los lenguajes antiguos _no oop_, y el propio Dijkstra previno ante esta práctica que suele ser muy propensa a errores.Normalmente acabas con una multitud de `ifs` anidados, y hace mucho que en lenguajes como C# se desaconseja esta teoría del "punto de salida unico"

Comment: Como ya comenté en [otra publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/69740/es-buena-practica-usar-return-en-funciones-o-metodos-void) en que hablo del "*punto de salida único*", esta práctica es más una cuestión estética que funcional y se sobrevalora su impacto (y también menciono a Dijkstra). Pero debo admitir que estéticamente, se ve más limpio el código (aunque yo usaría LINQ en lugar de una función adicional).

Comment: En este caso en el que solo hay una condición podemos estar de acuerdo en que el código parece mas limpio, pero mi comentario iba encaminado a aclarar que esa teoría del punto de salida único no tiene sentido en los lenguajes modernos, lo importante es que el código quede lo mas legible posible y no que solo exista un `return` en la función.

Answer (score 6):

Con `break` saldrás del bloque `while`

Con `return` saldrás de todo el método `ItemExist`. No es necesario añadir un break luego del `return` es más el compilador lo detectará como el warning `CS0162 Unreacheble code detected` es decir nunca podrá ser ejecutado ya que con el return acabará la ejecución del método `ItemExist` y el break nunca será alcanzado.

Comment: Entonces quedará mejor así **if(Invoke<bool> (item, "Exist", name)) return true;** y ya está. 

Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Un `return` dentro de un método devolverá inmediatamente el flujo del programa al código que llamó al método. En el ejemplo que pones, el `break` nunca se alcanzaría (de hecho,el Visual Studio probablemente te lanze un warning indicando código inalcanzable).